# Boost Graph library. Implement visitor that can revisit vertices multiple times

Tags: c++, boost, graph, breadth-first-search

I am pretty knew to the boost graph library. I need to implement a visitor that would be able to revisit the same vertices multiple times. For the undirectedS graphs (or directed with 2 edges) this would result in the infinite search depth, however I am planning to put a finite constraint on the maximum depth.

I am considering to use breadth_first_search(), and I think what I need to do is to un-mark visited vertices in vis.black_target()? Would you know how to do it?

Thanks!

EDIT: Technically I would like to explore all possible paths of a constant depth from a starting vertex. (even if some of them revisit the same vertices several times)

Comment: I am not sure I got your question right but how about doing the breadth_first_search several times?

Comment: Right, I was thinking about it, but this would mean that I have to recursively restart a new BFS from every discovered vertex (while maintaining keeping track of a global depth so far).